# How to change Twitter Bootstrap tab, when button is pressed?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, twitter-bootstrap

I need to change the tab when button is pressed, and the tab should be identified by id. The following code doesn't work for me - just the page is reloaded:

```
<div class="form-actions">
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-next">Next</button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn">Clear</button>
</div>
...
<div class="tab-pane active" id="2">
...

$("#btn-next").click(function(event) {
  $('#2').tab('show');
});
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
function nextTab(elem) {
  $(elem + ' li.active')
    .next()
    .find('a[data-toggle="tab"]')
    .click();
}
function prevTab(elem) {
  $(elem + ' li.active')
    .prev()
    .find('a[data-toggle="tab"]')
    .click();
}
```

and use `nextTab('#tab');` or `prevTab('#tab');`

**Live example** with continue actions:  http://jsbin.com/atinel/9/edit#javascript,html

Comment: Strange, but it doesn't work in my case (I use `'#2'` instead of `'#tab'`). And with live example it works only once (if I press Next second time, jsbin shows code). I use latest version of FF.

Comment: do not give numbers as ID's... always start with a letter!

Comment: @balexandre jsbin does have the error described by LA_, but works fine when put in my code. Thanks

Comment: @balexandre, usage of ids like `tabN` instead of just `N` doesn't help with original approach - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/BM973/1/, and yes, your code works well on jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/BM973/2/, the most important part, what I didn't get before: id `tab` should be assigned to `ul` and `#tab` (and not tab id as I thought) always should be used when function is called.

Comment: @balexandre, I've found one bug with such approach - when tabs contain a lot of text, scrolling to the top doesn't happen - http://jsfiddle.net/and7ey/BM973/10/

Comment: @LA_ you are returning `false` on the click! If you return `true` on the click, that will always jump to the top of the tab as they are links.

Comment: @balexandre, if I return `true`, then the form will be submitted, which I want to avoid.

Comment: @LA_ then you're doing something wrong, as a link should never submit a `<form>` by it's own, you should have only that on the last tab, ìf(lastTab) $(link).addClass(last)...` and you can fade everything and show a loading spinner instead.... or simply use `.animation()` to go to the top tab again.

Comment: @balexandre, please check my last example - this is what twitter bootstrap does if button is within `form fieldset .form-actions`.

Comment: hmm, even if I move it out and remove `return false`, then still it is not scrolled to the top.

Comment: @LA_ check my updated example, it's simple and all work perfectly: last step submits the form. in JSBin, click **Render** and test it.

Comment: @balexandre, which browser do you use to test it? http://jsbin.com/atinel/12/edit#preview - it scrolls to the top in Google Chrome and doesn't in FF (no more problem with form submission).

Comment: I've also tried to select next tab with keyboard, then scroll down and press enter - tab is changed, but still bottom is shown. Looks like `click` is not the best approach.

Answer (score 4):

What about using the `data-toggle="tab"` in an `<a>` tag? Something like:

```
  <a href="#2" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-next" data-toggle="tab">Next</a>
```

Comment: Yes, it shows next tab, but not fully correct - content of next tab is shown, but still first tab is highlighted as chosen.

Comment: I tried this on a href link within the content panel of say TAB 2 to open TAB 1 content panel, works perfect .. but the active tab status doesnt change. I am using proper href #id and data-toggle="tab" even tried adding class =active to the href, no go.. any ideas?