# change toggle tab on button clicked

Tags: c#, javascript, html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

i created 3 tabs by using bootstrap, everything is work fine.

but i needed to add a 'next button' inside the tab content, whenever user click on it will brings the user to next tab. how to write a script for that button, i wish to use asp:button control
fiddle: http://www.bootply.com/B2JQzjZDZH

javascript:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
              $('[data-toggle="btns"] .btn').on('click', function () {
                  var $this = $(this);
                  $this.parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
                  $this.addClass('active');
              });
          });
```

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group form-group" data-toggle="btns">
   <a class="btn btn-default active" href="#first" data-toggle="tab">step 1</a>
   <a class="btn btn-default" href="#second" data-toggle="tab">step 2</a>
   <a class="btn btn-default" href="#third" data-toggle="tab">step 3</a><br>
                    </div>
<div class="tab-content" runat="server" id="divContent">
<div class="tab-pane active" id="first">
content 1
  <button type="button">next</button>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="second">
content 2
  <button type="button">next</button>
</div>

<div class="tab-pane" id="third">
    content 3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change Twitter Bootstrap tab, when button is pressed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9252127/how-to-change-twitter-bootstrap-tab-when-button-is-pressed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally: You can activate individual tabs in several ways:

```
$('#myTab a[href="#profile"]').tab('show') // Select tab by name
$('#myTab a:first').tab('show') // Select first tab
$('#myTab a:last').tab('show') // Select last tab
$('#myTab li:eq(2) a').tab('show') // Select third tab (0-indexed)
```

From http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tabs

But, your HTML does not completely comply with the Bootstrap usage. To make this work, you should use:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id="myTab">
  <li class="active"><a href="#home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#profile" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#messages" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#settings" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="home">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="settings">...</div>
</div>
```

But, in your case you can also do it by changing the active class of the tab-panes and the tabs themselves.

Here is your example http://www.bootply.com/q00EhgVnSG

Comment: If you thought my answer was useful, please upvote it.